# Cowboy POST handler

Tags: rest, erlang, cowboy

Trying to receive the POST request and store it into ETS table

here is the code

```
init(Req0, Opts) ->
    Method = cowboy_req:method(Req0),
    HasBody = cowboy_req:has_body(Req0),
    Req = maybe_echo(Method, HasBody, Req0),
    {ok, Req, Opts}.

maybe_echo(<<"POST">>, true, Req0) ->
    {ok, PostVals, Req} = cowboy_req:read_urlencoded_body(Req0),
    Echo = proplists:get_value(<<"echo">>, PostVals),
    echo(Echo, Req);

maybe_echo(<<"POST">>, false, Req) ->
    cowboy_req:reply(400, [], <<"Missing body.">>, Req);

maybe_echo(_, _, Req) ->
    %% Method not allowed.
    cowboy_req:reply(405, Req).

echo(undefined, Req) ->
    cowboy_req:reply(400, [], <<"Missing echo parameter.">>, Req);

echo(Echo, Req) ->
Inf = #news{id=25, created=today, article=Echo},
    case ets:insert(news, {Inf#news.id, Inf#news.created, Inf#news.article}) of
        true -> cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain; charset=utf-8">>}, Echo, Req);
        _        -> 
            Error = <<"{\"error\": \"error\"}">>,
            cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain; charset=utf-8">>}, Error, Req)
    end.
```

when i curl :

$ curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d echo='{"action":"insert","key":"some_key", "value":[1,2,3]}' http://localhost:8080/

I'm getting the error:

=ERROR REPORT==== 29-Jan-2017::18:57:21 ===
Ranch listener http, connection process <0.240.0>, stream 1 had its request process <0.241.0> exit with reason badarg and stacktrace [{ets,insert,[news,{25,today,<<"{\"action\":\"insert\",\"key\":\"some_key\", \"value\":[1,2,3]}">>}],[]},{post_handler,echo,2,[{file,"e:/_dev/news/_build/default/lib/news/src/post_handler.erl"},{line,25}]},{post_handler,init,2,[{file,"e:/_dev/news/_build/default/lib/news/src/post_handler.erl"},{line,8}]},{cowboy_handler,execute,2,[{file,"e:/_dev/news/_build/default/lib/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl"},{line,39}]},{cowboy_stream_h,execute,3,[{file,"e:/_dev/news/_build/default/lib/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl"},{line,173}]},{cowboy_stream_h,proc_lib_hack,3,[{file,"e:/_dev/news/_build/default/lib/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl"},{line,158}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]

but when I use echo like this:

```
echo(Echo, Req) ->
    cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain; charset=utf-8">>}, Echo, Req)
        end.
```

I receive the request - ({"action":"insert","key":"some_key", "value":[1,2,3]})

so seems like there is something with ETS? but I have no idea where I messed up

Creating ets in other module

ets:new(news, [ordered_set, protected, named_table, {keypos,1}, {read_concurrency, true}, {write_concurrency, true}])

could you please show me the right dirrection to resolve this issue

Comment: How/where are you creating the ETS table? Are you sure it's a `named_table` and the name is `news`?

Comment: @Dogbert I've created it in start module like this

-record(news, {id, created, article}).
 
Tab = ets:new(news, [ordered_set, protected, named_table, {keypos,1}, {read_concurrency, true}, {write_concurrency, true}]),
{ok, Tab}.

Comment: @Qbeck, you should edit that into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `protected` option in the `ets:new` call means that only the process creating the ETS table will be allowed to `insert` data. Other processes can only read the data.

Use `public` instead and all processes will have read/write access.

Comment: You're totally right. Working perfectly now. Thx. Much appreciated